# getting and adding data to existing SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, multi-table

im trying to get the data from a table then add it to another table. i need the `KEY_CATEGORYID`which auto increments from table 1 and then i need to add it to table 2 and 4. i cant
figure out how to do this as `KEY_CATEGORYID` will only have a value after the `createBudget` method has finished and that happens after `addId` is finished this has me completely stumped on what to do any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public SQLiteDatabase createBudget(String bname, String bpay, String bamount,
                String bmemo) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ContentValues t1 = new ContentValues();
            ContentValues t2 = new ContentValues();
            ContentValues t4 = new ContentValues();
            t1.put(KEY_NAME, bname);
            t1.put(KEY_PAYDAY,bpay);
            t2.put(KEY_AMOUNT, bamount);
            t2.put(KEY_DATE, date);
            t4.put(KEY_MEMO, bmemo);
            t4.put(KEY_DATE,date);

            ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE1, null, t1);
            ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null, t2);
            ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE4, null, t4);
            addID(bname);
        return ourDatabase;
        }
    private void addID(String bname) throws SQLException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ContentValues num = new ContentValues();
                List<String> nums = new ArrayList<String>();
                int number = 0;
                String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_CATEGORYID};        
                Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE1, columns,KEY_CATEGORYID + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(bname)}, null, null, null, null);
                if(c!= null)
                {
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) { 
                        nums.add(c.getString(0));
                        number = nums.get(0);
                        }
                    num.put(KEY_CATEGORYID, number);
                }
                ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null, num);
                ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE4, null, num);
            }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application/9109728#9109728

Answer (score 0):

The `insert` method returns the autogenerated key value:

```java
long key = ourDB.insert(TABLE1, null, t1);
t2.put(KEY_CATEGORYID, key);
ourDB.insert(TABLE2, null, t2);
```